# Why do I get TCP/IP error when trying to create DB in my Lambda?

Tags: mysql, django, lambda, zappa

So I'm trying to deploy my Django project using lambda, with zappa. I'm using MySQL for DB engine. Now after doing some research, I realized that I needed to create a custom Django command to create DB, since I'm using MySQL. So I created `crate_db` command, `zappa update`d, then ran `zappa manage dev create_db`. Then I got this error: 
 `2004 (HY000): Can't create TCP/IP socket (97)` 
below is my `create_db.py` file, for your information.

```
import sys
import logging
import mysql.connector
import os

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.conf import settings

rds_host = os.environ.get("MY HOST")
db_name =  os.environ.get("")
user_name =  os.environ.get("MY USERNAME")
password =  os.environ.get("MY PASSWORD")
port = os.environ.get("3306")

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates the initial database'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Starting db creation')
        try:
            db = mysql.connector.connect(host=rds_host, user=user_name,
                                 password=password, db="mysql", connect_timeout=10)
            c = db.cursor()
            print("connected to db server")
            c.execute("""CREATE DATABASE bookcake_db;""")
            c.execute("""GRANT ALL ON bookcake_db.* TO 'ryan'@'%'""")
            c.close()
            print("closed db connection")
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            logger.error("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
            sys.exit()
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Does `rds_host` get a value and, if so, what is the value of it?

Comment: @Luuk The value is the endpoint of my RDS instance.

Comment: Are you able to make a connection using the mysql client (to your RAD instance) ?

Comment: @Luuk Hmm I'm not sure how to check it. I'm actually new to AWS :( Is it able to check it in AWS console?

Comment: I am newer to RDS, I do not even have acces to it, not even in AWS console.  From the console something like `mysql -h <rds_host> -u <username>`, should prompt for your password.

Comment: Seems like either you don't have the right mysql module installed or the Lambda instance cannot connect to RDS.  Is your RDS in a VPC?  By the way, if you are creating the RDS instance you can also create the database at the same time.